# How would you move a full backbone.js tree?

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, backbone.js, client-side

I have a backbone model, that model has some collections, those collections have some models, those models might have collections and so on.

I need to be able to take this model on one client and replicate every bit of it on another client where no part of it already exists.

I've been thinking about some type of recursive function that can break down the model and go down each branch of the tree, but I'm not sure about rebuilding it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: are you keeping these models/collections as attributes or directly on the models/attributes?

Comment: @TomTu I can store them either way.

Comment: @TomTu I'm thinking I will need to store some level of relational data in each one. At least a parent/children set up to be able to recurse through the tree. Maybe backbone-rel but that might be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Backbone.js doesn't include support for nested models and collections [by default](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-nested). However, there are some solutions listed on [their wiki](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Extensions%2C-Plugins%2C-Resources).

Just to list a few off that page:

- [Backbone-Nested](http://afeld.github.com/backbone-nested/)
- [nesting.js](https://gist.github.com/1610397)